# xcode 4.2 ios5 codesign failed with exit code 1

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4.2, ios5

I've searched all over the google for a solution which works for me... I've tried SO many different suggestions.. but nothing seems to be working.

In xcode 4.2 using ios5 when I try to run the project, I get the following error

```
    CodeSign /Users/matt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-apjchwtbrxazuighfwhrzxchpcfk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.app
    cd /Users/matt/Desktop/myapp_v1_1
    setenv CODESIGN_ALLOCATE /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign "iPhone Developer: Richard Sawyer (JCC5D2QGAM)" --resource-rules=/Users/matt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-apjchwtbrxazuighfwhrzxchpcfk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.app/ResourceRules.plist --entitlements /Users/matt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-apjchwtbrxazuighfwhrzxchpcfk/Build/Intermediates/myapp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.build/myapp.xcent /Users/matt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-apjchwtbrxazuighfwhrzxchpcfk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.app

/Users/matt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-apjchwtbrxazuighfwhrzxchpcfk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/myapp.app: object file format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

I have tried

- reinstalling xcode
- deleting the DerivedData folder
- adding resource location files (somewhere?!)
- checking for duplicate info.plist files
- creating a symm (?) Link to the code sign folder
- other random little bits and bobs

It seems nothing is working! I don't think I changed anything for this not to work. I was testing on my iPhone 4S, then tried on an iPhone 3G (os 3.1.2) - I actually changed the settings to add armv6, but have tried to change this back with no avail.

I'm not sure what I can do now?!

Thanks for any help.... anything at all!

Comment: Have you got a valid provisionning profile, with you as a developper, the device you're running on and the app bundle id?

Comment: Try deleting any leftover, expired provisionning profiles on the device.

Comment: Thanks - I've removed all the profiles from the device and cleaned everything up. I used organiser to manage the team profile. In xCode it says "iPhone developer - currently matches 'iPhone developer: Richard Sawyer (JCC5D2QGAM) in iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem turned out to be the wrong setting in `Build Options`.

I had entered `armv6` and `armv7` as settings in there. I changed these back to `normal` and it built fine.

[image: build settings]

Answer (score 0):

Check the organizer/devices listing of mobile provisionings to make sure you have a provisioning that corresponds to "iPhone Developer: Richard Sawyer (JCC5D2QGAM)" and is valid.  In any case, probably want to go through the iTunes Provisioning Portal and follow every direction from the beginning absolutely precisely.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the comprehensive DTS Tech Note on all things CodeSigning-related:

https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933