# Supported Platforms for iPad app?

Tags: ios, ipad, bundle, target, platform

I'm creating an app for iPad (my first), and I was about to submit a binary until I noticed something peculiar in the target build settings. Under the "Supported Platforms" key, it say "iphonesimulator iphoneos". Additionally, it says "build/appname.build/AppStore-iphoneos" under Per-configuration Intermediate Build File Paths. However, the app is supposed to be built for iPad. In the summary, the iOS Application Target Devices specifies "iPad". Note that I originally created the app to be universal, but would now only like to release it as an iPad app.

[image: App Target Build Settings]

**SOLVED**: A note to anyone who might have the same question. I did not initially change the Build Variants from "iphonesimulator iphoneos", but I ultimately had to because I had a code sign problem, in which the Build Variants must be set to "normal" in order to compile. See this post for further info, it helped me:
[Code Sign Failed - Exit Code: 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052925/xcode-4-2-ios5-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1/8309139#comment10590365_8309139)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this a question?  Once you submit to the store, you'll mark the app as being available for iPad only.

The SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS conditional is meant for libraries that can be compiled for both MacOS and iOS (a.k.a. iPhoneOS... there is no such thing as iPadOS). It can also be used for libraries that build to work on only the device (such as things that utilize hardware connectors) and not the simulator.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, but do I need to replace iphoneos with something like ipados?

Comment: Urk... NO!  let's not do that.  Leave them both as is.  When you submit to the store, just mark the app as being available for iPad only.  I'll modify my answer to note this and do some more research really quickly.

Comment: Yep... apple.com doesn't say anything useful about the SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS define.  Leave them as is.